# How to consolidate output based on highest value in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have the following input where a user watched a program in the following percentages (25 or 50 or 75 or 100).I just want to calculate the highest percentage viewed by a certain user on a certain id.
The inputs and outputs are given below.

## Input

```
id1, u1, watched25
id2, u1, watched25
id1, u1, watched50
id1, u1, watched75
id3, u1, watched25
id4, u1, watched25
id1, u1, watched100
id2, u1, watched50
id5, u1, watched25
id5, u1, watched50
id5, u1, watched75
id5, u1, watched100
id1, u2, watched25
id1, u2, watched50
id3, u2, watched25
id3, u3, watched25
id1, u2, watched75
id4, u3, watched25
id4, u3, watched50
```

## Desired output

```
id1, u1, watched100
id2, u1, watched50
id3, u1, watched25
id5, u1, watched25
id5, u1, watched100
id1, u2, watched75
id3, u2, watched25
id3, u3, watched25
id4, u3, watched50
```

Comment: For start, I'd drop the prefix "watched" in the third column: having a numerical value is more efficient in terms of used storage, and much more practical when you'll compare values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does what you ask.

```
select id, u, max(cast(substr(w, 9) as int)) 
from my_table 
group by id, u 
order by u, id
```

There's a few things combined here. Let me unpack the important bits.

First I discard the `"watched"` portion of the third column using `substr(w, 8)` (substring starting from the eighth letter), then I convert this value to a number using `cast(X as int)` and finally I use `group by` and `max()` to retain only the highest value for each `id, u` tuple. I added the `order by` clause to match the sorting of your desired output example.

Running this on your input results in the following output.

```
id1  u1 100
id2  u1 50
id3  u1 25
id4  u1 25
id5  u1 100
id1  u2 75
id3  u2 25
id3  u3 25
id4  u3 50
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pig to achieve this (assuming percentage is numeric)

```
a = LOAD 'input' as (id:chararray, user:chararray, percentage:int);
b = group a by (id, user);
c = foreach b generate group.id, group.user, MAX(a.percentage) as highest;

STORE c into 'output';
```

Comment: I think Lukas's answer uses hive